# Negative values from my raster do not appear on my new raster

Tags: r, raster

I have a problem with my raster that I can't figure out.

I want to retrieve a `Spatraster` (representing climatic conditions in world) using `crop` in a given countries. However, when I `crop` this raster only in North America countries (i.e. US and Canada), the negative values in the initial raster are not saved, even though they should be.

```
require(countrycode)
ISO <- countrycode(c("US", "Canada"), origin = 'country.name', destination = 'iso3c')
[1] "USA" "CAN"
# shapefile
require(geodata)
shp <- gadm(country=ISO, level=0, 
                  path = ("North_Am", "Shapefile", sep="/"),
                  version="latest")

shp <- crop(shp, ext(-170, -50, 25, 90))

# climatic raster
r <- "Bio6_1981-2010.tif" %>% rast(.)

datatype(r)
"INT2U"

require(terra)
cshp <- crop(r, shp, mask=TRUE)
cshp
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 6973, 14086, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -170.0001, -52.61681, 24.99986, 83.10819  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : memory
name        : Bio6_1981-2010 
min value   :              0 #I'm losing the negative values, when I shouldn't be
max value   :             20

plot(cshp)
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Couple of things going on here. You create a raster object called "r", you go on to call "r" in `compareCRS()`, but your `crop()` function calls an object called "x". Also, never create an object called "c", it can cause problems as `c()` is a function in base R. Let me know if these suggestions don't help, as there may be other things to try.

Comment: Thanks for your suggests, sorry I was a mistake because I named `x`and not `r`in my script, it's fixed, and I've replaced `c` with `cshp` but the problem persists.

Comment: Ok, now run `datatype(r)` and `datatype(cshp)` and let me know the result. Also, how do you know there are negative values within your clip extent?

Comment: Both `datatype()` reply "INT2U". I know that I should have negative values because when I do exactly the same thing in France, I have no problems and a minimum value of -32.25, I'll add it to my question.

Comment: It is not possible to have negative values in an INT2U raster, [see here for more info](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/dataType.html). Your original "Bio6_1951-1980.tif" data are most likely an INT2U raster. That's because `rast()` doesn't modify the data type, "it only reads the parameters that describe the geometry." And comparing two different areas is not proof that negative values exist in your US clip extent. Without the data in front of me I can't offer anything else. Good luck!

Comment: Have a look ar the source of your France data, it is from memory. However, the source of your US data is "spat_B9XqQpthrkqVY7J_480.tif ". In other words, you've done something different in your process.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, the problem comes from the data type of my initial raster,  when I open it with `rast` function.
The raster is opened in "INT2U" data type, which cannot contain a negative value [(more info here)](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/dataType.html).

I then need to convert it to another data type, such as "FLT4S".

```
r <- writeRaster(r, 'new.grd', datatype='FLT4S', overwrite=TRUE)
datatype(r)
"FLT4S"
```